# Get daily average by column even though there are empty dates in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in mysql called `trans` with the following structure:

```
trans (
   id number
   date date
   amount number
)
```

The date is stored in the following format: `2021-09-21`

I am trying to make a selection out of this table that will give me a daily average of the `amount` column.

But not just as simple as `select avg(amount)`, because i'm trying to get the total average even tough there are days in which i don't have any amount.

For example, let's take 5 pairs (date - amount):

```
2021-09-21 - 100
2021-09-22 - 120
2021-09-24 - 140
2021-09-25 - 300
2021-09-28 - 450
```

If i have these values in the table, and do the AVG() i would get 1110 : 5 = 222. However, in between these dates there are dates that are empty (23,26,27 th of 09). So the daily avg is not correct, because those days are not take into account, right?

The daily avg should be

```
2021-09-21 - 100
2021-09-22 - 120
2021-09-23 - 0
2021-09-24 - 140
2021-09-25 - 300
2021-09-26 - 0
2021-09-27 - 0
2021-09-28 - 450
```

Meaning 1110 / 8 = 138.75.

So i want to select this 138.75 value. Does anyone know a solution for this?
I don't want to alter the entries in any way, so I don't want to insert 0 values in between the non empty dates.

Thank you!

Comment: Why not use AVG() and exclude the zero amounts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First 2 user defined variables:

```
mysql> SET @MinDate = (SELECT MIN(date) FROM trans);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET @MaxDate = (SELECT MAX(date) FROM trans);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

Then SQL Code:

```
mysql> SELECT SUM(amount) / (DATEDIFF(@MaxDate,@MinDate) + 1) FROM trans;
+-------------------------------------------------+
| SUM(amount) / (DATEDIFF(@MaxDate,@MinDate) + 1) |
+-------------------------------------------------+
|                                        138.7500 |
+-------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Sum()` and `DateDiff()` function to calculate your average in this case.
Below SQL query will work for your usecase -

```
SELECT SUM(amount)/(DATEDIFF('2021/09/28', '2021/09/21') + 1) as Avg FROM trans Where date between '2021/09/21' and '2021/09/28';
```

Comment: You either need `TIMESTAMPDIFF(day, '2021-09-21', '2021-09-28')` or `DATEDIFF('2021-09-28', '2021-09-21')` (without `DAY` argument and dates in reversed order). You also need `+1`, because between 21 and 28 are 8 days, but 28-21 = 7.

Comment: Yes we need to add ``+1`` also. I have edited my answer. But ``DATEDIFF()`` with **day** parameter works fine. I have tested it.

Comment: [`DATEDIFF(expr1,expr2)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff)

Comment: Yes you are right. I got confused with SQL server syntax.